# Задача на циклы в Python

Tags: python, list, циклы, datetime

Есть список дат, в котором дню отдали один символ, а месяцу - два (все даты корректны, несуществующих дней нет). Сравните данные из списка с текущей датой. Если дата в списке совпадает с сегодняшней - вывести `True`, если нет - `False`.

```
dates_list = ['11.07', '23.01', '3.12', '4.09', '10.03', '14.02', '2.05']
```

Что смог сделать:

```
# Сперва создаю переменные, которые будут проверять текущую дату (день и месяц):

import datetime

day = datetime.datetime.now().day # возвращает текущий день 1-31 без 0
month = datetime.datetime.now().month # возвращает текущий месяц 1-12 без 0

# привожу month к нужному виду:

if len(str(month)) == 1:
    month = '0' + str(month)

# теперь month 01-12
```

А что делать дальше - не пойму, какой цикл создать, как пройтись по дням и месяцам в списке.
Заранее благодарю за помощь и потраченное время.

Comment: Что вы имеете ввиду под  "дню отдали один символ" особенно на примерах дат '11.07', '23.01', '10.03', '14.02'?

Comment: То, что если день < 10 - 0 не пишется, т.е. 1.03, 2.04 и тд.

Comment: А если день >10?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

В одну строку

```py
print(f"{day}.{month}" in dates_list)
```

f-строка понимает переменные в фигурных скобках, а далее вы просто спрашиваете "Есть ли данная строка в списке"

На выходе будете иметь одно из булевых значений `True/False`

вызовем с начальным списком

```py
dates_list = ['11.07', '23.01', '3.12', '4.09', '10.03', '14.02', '2.05']
print(f"{day}.{month}" in dates_list)

# out
# False
```

Добавим дату от сегодня и снова проверим

```py
dates_list.append("31.01")
print(f"{day}.{month}" in dates_list)

# out
# True
```

Comment: Действительно, очень просто! Спасибо большое, это работает.

Comment: @eomphe обратите внимание на небольшую "странность" сообщества: здесь не принято говорить "спасибо" в комментариях. [Что делать с ответами на мой вопрос](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/help/someone-answers). На здоровье

Answer (score 2):

Мне кажется более правильным подходом будет использование нормализованного  представления дня месяца в списке `dates_list` - т.е. преобразовать его таким образом, чтобы день месяца всегда состоял из двух цифр. Это позволит упростить  проверку. Кроме того, операция проверки принадлежности `element in <list>` имеет среднюю асимптотическую сложность `O(n)`, а `element in <set>` - `O(1)`. Поэтому для частых проверок имеет смысл преобразовать `dates_list` во множество (`set`).

Пример:

```
dates_list = ['11.07', '23.01', '3.12', '4.09', '10.03', '14.02', '2.05']
dates = set([x.zfill(5) for x in dates_list])
```

проверка на принадлежность:

```
datetime.datetime.now().strftime("%d.%m") in dates
```

Comment: tuple тоже имеет сложность O(n), при такой операции? Нашел ответ, ДА! `set` тип данных лучшее решение в данном случае

Comment: @Dmitry, по-моему "time complexity" совпадают у списков и кортежей `TimeComplexity` для одинаковых операций. [Таблица "TimeComplexity" для Python операций](https://wiki.python.org/moin/TimeComplexity)

Comment: точно, абсолютное совпадение по всем операциям, которые поддерживает tuple

Comment: Интересный способ реализации. Но как в таком случае вывести нужную нам дату из списка? Если использовать вариант от @Dmitry, это очень просто сделать (today = f"{day}.{month}").

Comment: @eomphe здесь идёт акцент на нормализации и ускорение поиска при частых проверках. Если у вас входные данные будут в таком виде + относительно не часто обращаться к данному поиску, то моё решение релевантно. Но к решению через множество я вам советую вернуться в будущем

Comment: @eomphe, не совсем понял... Вам нужно выводить совпавшую дату из списка в __оригинальном формате__? Вы об этом не упоминали в вопросе...

Comment: Нет, не нужно. Я просто уточнил, возможно ли это вообще, если использовать Вашу реализацию.

Comment: @eomphe, нет, если бы было подобное требование - я бы приводил вывод `datetime.datetime.now()` к формату без лидирующего нуля. Но мне такой подход не очень нравится, т.к. это усложняет код и делает его менее элегантным и понятным. PS это мое сугубо субъективное мнение)